# Diagnosing error in deploying GAE flex app

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I've been using GAE flex for awhile now, and all of a sudden my deploy process ends on the command line with:

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Flex operation
>   projects/MY-PROJECT/regions/us-central1/operations/xxx
>   error [DEADLINE_EXCEEDED]: An internal error occurred while processing
>   task
>   /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2019-09-04T21:29:03.412Z8424.ow.0:
>   Gave up polling Deployment Manager operation
>   MY-PROJECT/operation-xxx.

My logs don't have any helpful info.  These are relevant logs from the deployment:

```
2019-09-04T14:07:07Z [2019-09-04 14:07:07 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-09-04T14:07:06Z [2019-09-04 14:07:06 +0000] [16] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 16)
2019-09-04T14:07:06Z [2019-09-04 14:07:06 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
2019-09-04T14:07:05Z [2019-09-04 14:07:05 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)
2019-09-04T14:07:05Z [2019-09-04 14:07:05 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-09-04T14:07:05Z [2019-09-04 14:07:05 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-09-04T14:07:05Z [2019-09-04 14:07:05 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2019-09-04T14:07:05Z [2019-09-04 14:07:05 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2019-09-04T14:07:05Z [2019-09-04 14:07:05 +0000] [1] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2019-09-04T14:03:04Z [2019-09-04 14:03:04 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (1)
2019-09-04T14:03:03Z [2019-09-04 14:03:03 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
```

The instance exists in the console and appears to be running, but it just returns a 404.  The code runs fine locally.

Any ideas for how to diagnose what is going on?

I wonder if Google reduced a default deadline since the current deadline appears to be 4 minutes and my build has always taken longer than 4 minutes.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the deadline with the `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout` command to see if it resolves the issue?

Comment: @pessolato, I did try that.  The default is 10 min and I manually set it to 10 min (in case the default has somehow changed), but my build is still crashing out at 4 min.

Comment: @pessolato, I also upped it to 20 min but still not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured this out and it is kind of a crazy Google Cloud bug.  TL; DR -- Don't use [Google Cloud Organization Policy Constraints](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints).

Here is what happened according to my best understanding:

- For my Google Cloud project, I picked the `us-central` region.
- About 6 months ago I set a Google Cloud policy constraint for my organization so that I would use only US-based resources.  This set a policy that allowed US resources **that existed at that time**.
- My recent deploys of my flex app were being deployed to the `us-central1-f` zone.  I believe Google picked the zone and I don't have control over that.
- The `us-central1-f` was not allowed by my location policy because that zone did not exist at the time I set my location policy.
- This caused my deploy to crash with the unhelpful error message in my question.

The way I figured this out was that I deployed Google's hello world flask app, and when deploying that app, I received a more helpful error message that allowed me to understand the problem.